# Next.js trying to push input value into json, but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, forms, input, next.js

Right there I'm trying to get value from inout, and after that change it in json.

1. Json file is correct, and value from it is also correct, so when I'm trying to output PcosData....Title - everything is okay
2. the serverside has also no problems, as in terminal i get (get & POST), and data which is in POST is also returning, that means - a) server gets input value b) backend is correct

so the problem. is in frontend, I think I'm doing something wrongg when I'm trying to push data in HandleSubmit or smth like that

```
import PcosData from "/data/pcos.json";
import {useEffect} from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import util from "util";

const getBody = util.promisify(bodyParser.urlencoded());

export async function getServerSideProps({req, res}) {
    await getBody(req, res);
    console.log(req.method, req.body);
    return {
        props: {
            // status
        }
    }
}

export default function adminPcos() {



        const [title, setTitle] = useState(PcosData["pcos-first"].title);

        


        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            // e.preventDefault();
            PcosData["pcos-first"].title = title;
            console.log(handleSubmit)

        }



    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello world</h1>

            {PcosData["pcos-first"].map((pcosdata) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} key={ pcosdata.id } method="post">
                    

                    <input type="text" className="name" name="title" defaultValue={pcosdata.title} onChange={(e) => setTitle({text: e.target.value})}/>
                    
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            ))}

        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Use `setTitle(title)`

Comment: Instead of this - setTitle({text: e.target.value}) ?

 If yes - it is still not working(